# ASM ByteCode: prepending visitMethodInsn with another invocation

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Suppose I want to call a (logging) method **before** the invocation of some method of interest. This means that when listening for visitMethodInsn the stack is already populated with the arguments for the method(s) of interest.

Is it possible to then store the current stack somewhere, call the log and repopulate the stack? Am I missing any obvious stack mutation operators? Or do I really need to either:

- store the stack in variables temporarily
- buffer all stack mutation calls until a method invocation to replay the buffer after my (possibly not applicable) logging invocation?

**Example**: given the original code

```
public static void main() 
{
  doSomethingUnrelated();

  methodOfInterest(); // line 5 for example

  doSomethingUnrelated();
}
```

the resulting code should be like:

```
public static void main() 
{
  doSomethingUnrelated();

  Logger.log("methodOfInterest", "main", 5); 
  methodOfInterest();

  doSomethingUnrelated();
}

public Logger 
{
  public static void log(String method, String callee, int line) 
  { ... }
}
```

---

Context: my actual ASM MethodVisitor looks like this:

```
class UsageClassMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor implements Opcodes
{
    private final String fileName;
    private final String visitedClass;
    private final String visitedMethod;
    private int lineNumber;

    UsageClassMethodVisitor(MethodVisitor mv, String fileName, String visitedClass, String visitedMethod, boolean isStatic)
    {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, mv);
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.visitedClass = visitedClass;
        this.visitedMethod = visitedMethod;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLineNumber(int i, Label label) {
        lineNumber = i;
        super.visitLineNumber(i, label);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int access, String ownerClass, String method, String signature, boolean isInterface) {
        if(ownerClass.contains("org/example/package/")) {
            System.out.printf("prepending to visitMethodInsn(%s, %s, %s, %b) @ %s.%s:%d\n",
                    ownerClass, method, signature, isInterface,
                    visitedClass, visitedMethod, lineNumber);
            super.visitLdcInsn(fileName);
            super.visitLdcInsn(visitedClass);
            super.visitLdcInsn(visitedMethod);
            super.visitLdcInsn(lineNumber);
            super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
                    Hook.ACCESS_OWNER_NAME,
                    Hook.ACCESS_METHOD_NAME,
                    Hook.ACCESS_METHOD_DESC, false);
        }
        super.visitMethodInsn(access, ownerClass, method, signature, isInterface);
    }
}
```

but obviously this is throwing an error as the stack is 8 long instead of 4 at the time of invocation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org.using.package.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @13: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type integer (current frame, stack[8]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/String'
  Current Frame:
bci: @13
flags: { }
locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
stack: { long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd, 'java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', integer }
```

Comment: Not sure why you are pushing a file name. Note: `long` takes 2 slots so you have 7 values on the stack with the last position being the slot 8 (which is the 9th slot starting at 0)

Comment: What are ACCESS_METHOD_NAME / DESC?

Comment: Those are in a file which exposes the hooks to call. See http://www.slideshare.net/Takipi/advanced-production-debugging#33 for an example from Takipi.

Comment: I didn't mean their purpose, I meant are they referring to the right method?

Comment: that was indeed the problem, tnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to store the stack anywhere, because, the stack is well, a stack. You can just push the log arguments, call the logging function, pop the result, and you'll have the original stack still in place.

Comment: Never mind, the problem was related to calling the wrong method. I used Hook.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].getName() for both declared method 0 and 1 but their order got changed during compilation.